# How to remove y-axis from grouped bar chart

Tags: r

I would like to remove the y-axis from my graph. Please see reproducible code below. Is there a way to do this?

```
data <- structure(list(
A= c(53, 39),
B = c(30, 36), 
C = c(12, 19), 
D = c(5, 6)), 
.Names = c("Poor", "Fair", "Good", "Excellent"), 
class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -2L))

attach(data)
print(data)
colors <- c("dodgerblue3","red3")
barplot(as.matrix(data), 
    main="",
    beside = T, ylab = "", ylim = range(0,65),  col=colors, border=F)

legend(5,60,  legend=c("Fox News", "CNN"), 
   fill=colors, horiz = T, bty='n')
text(1.5, 55, "53%")
text(2.5, 41, "39%")
text(4.5, 32, "30%")
text(5.5, 38, "36%")
text(7.5, 14, "12%")
text(8.5, 21, "19%")
text(10.5, 7, "5%")
text(11.5, 8, "6%")`
```

Comment: `yaxt="n"` in your `barplot` call. See `?par` for all the fun options in base plotting.

Comment: Thanks! Is there also a way to remove the border around the legend boxes?

Comment: Seek, and ye shall find - in `?legend` - `bty: the type of box to be drawn around the legend`.

Comment: ...and `border: the border color for the boxes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `?par`, you can find all the settings, which would point you to `yaxt="n"`:

You can also save off the barplot positions when plotting, and use that to generate your percentage labels automatically.

```
colors <- c("dodgerblue3","red3")
bp <- barplot(as.matrix(data),  main="", beside = T, ylab = "",
              ylim = range(0,65), col=colors, border=FALSE, yaxt="n")
text(x=bp, y=unlist(data) + 2, labels=unlist(data))
legend(5,60,  legend=c("Fox News", "CNN"), fill=colors, horiz = TRUE, bty='n', border=0)
```